# Regular expression statement inside a while loop only matching and printing one of several expected matches

Tags: regex, perl

I've been struggling with this for a while and I was wondering if there was something obvious I've missed.

As programming learning/practice, I'm trying to put together a simple script for calculating the components of a restriction enzyme digest mix. However, first I need to get a list of enzyme stock concentrations.

I pulled all the individual pages from the New England Biolabs [enzyme page](http://www.neb.com/nebecomm/tech_reference/restriction_enzymes/buffer_activity_restriction_enzymes.asp?), and my goal with this current script is to pull out the name of the enzyme and the concentrations available from the company.

This example works with a local copy of EcoRI (link included at bottom of submission).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open(FILE,'productR0101.asp');
my $line;
my $counter;
my $array1;
my $array2;
my $array3;
my $concentration;
my @array4;
$counter = 1;

while ($line = <FILE>) {
    chomp($line);

    if ($counter == 6 ){
        $array1 = $line;
        $counter++;
    }
    else{
        $counter++;
    }

    if ($line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g) {
        (@array4) =$line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g;
        print @array4;
    }
}
print "\n".$array1;
exit;
```

Every file has the enzyme name on the sixth line of the file, so I just pulled that whole line. However, the concentrations are in different locations, so my approach was to read in the file one line at a time, and match to the `units/ml` tag.

My thinking was that it should print out the match for each line, if there was one, every time the while loop runs, effectively resulting in a string of separate print statements.

This is where I get messed up. There are six different locations in this file with a `units/ml` tag: three for `20,000` and three for `100,000`.

I was expecting six different results printed, but when I run this, only one `100,000 units/ml` result is returned.

I've tried all sorts of fixes. I tried concatenating strings, I tried storing it as a string, I tried concatenating it onto another array that never gets touched by the `(@array4) = $line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g` line, and it either breaks it or gives the same result.

And finally, I apologize for any weird conventions. I'm still learning Perl, and my first experience programming was with MATLAB.

Also, the `$array1`, `$array2`, etc. exist because I was trying to keep track of exactly what was getting put where; my intention is to clean it up once I get it functional.

So does anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: the data source is the source code to each individual enzyme page. For this example, if you view the [page source](http://www.neb.com/nebecomm/products/productR0101.asp) you get the complete input file I gave to the script.

Comment: We need a sample of the data file please

Comment: Looks like the data file is the raw http document from the EcoRI link in the original post.

Comment: Yes, Chris is correct. I edited my submission to make this more clear.

Comment: I'm still not clear whether you are processing the HTML that is returned by the link you gave or something more simple

Comment: It's just the HTML. I have a folder full of *.asp files where each is the web-page for each individual enzyme product page. There's nowhere else on their site where the concentration for each solution is listed, except for their individual product pages. My goal was to collect all those concentrations so I can construct a table that includes that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We really need to see the data you are processing, but it looks like you are storing only the *last* occurrence of `/units.ml/` in `@array4` because you are reading the file line by line.

I will add to this answer if you supplement your question, but for now I need to know

- What your data looks like
- What the mysterious `/.{8}/` is for
- Are you aware that `$array1`, `$array2`, and `$array3`, are *scalars*, as well as being very bad names for variables?

For now, here is a rewrite of your code using idiomatic Perl, and the `$.` variable that evaluates to the line number of the file most recently read

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file, '<', 'productR0101.asp' or die $!;

my $array1;
my @array4;

while (my $line = <$file>) {

  chomp $line;

  $array1 = $line if $. == 6;

  if ($line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/) {
    @array4 = $line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g;
    print "@array4\n";
  }
}

print "\n".$array1;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment! The original data I used was the source code to this page: http://www.neb.com/nebecomm/products/productR0101.asp . I used the /.{8}/ because I was trying to use the "units/ml" phrase as an anchor for the search pattern, then retrieving the previous 8 characters, which would include the concentration of the solution. I do know they're bad variable names, but I think I'm missing the significance of their being scalars. Aren't strings stored in scalars regularly?

However, your modified code turned out to give exactly the results I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes strings are stored in scalars, but an *array* is an ordered collection of scalars and I'm not sure what you intended here. The code is probably still wrong. To match something like `100,000 units/ml` you should say explicitly what you want to capture. `my ($conc) = m|([0-9,]+)\s+units/ml|` would put, say, `20,000` into `$conc`

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up. I think you're probably right about the code still being wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest you experiment, read the documentation and look at Perl code written by people you respect. Learning a programming language is no less comlicate than learning a natural language, and it takes a while to be able to write idiomatically

Answer (score 1):

Are the `20,000 units/ml` at the start of the line? Because in that case, `.{8}` would fail to match - the dot doesn't match newlines, and `20,000_` is only 7 characters.

Comment: For the first four instances, there are four tab characters preceding the 20,000 units/ml. For the final two instances, both the 20,000 and 100,000 instances are buried deep within a line, so character limits shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly reproduce the behavior you've reported of only getting one of the 100,000 units/ml results, as I'm not exactly sure what your input data is.  However, I think the problem is with the regular expression not having any captures.  You should put parenthesis around the part of the regex match that you want to be returned to @array4.  So instead of this:

```
@array4 = $line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g;
```

Try this:

<s>@array4 = $line =~ m/(.{8})units.ml/g;</s>

```
@array4 = $line =~ /(.{8})units.ml/;
```

EDIT:
You also don't want to use the m/ and /g modifiers.

Comment: Oh, okay. I didn't know about the parentheses returning the regex match to the array. I was assuming the whole match would be returned. Thanks for pointing that out! And I can see how I wouldn't need the /g operator, but would the reason why I wouldn't use the m/ operator be because it's unnecessary in this case?

Comment: Hm... on closer inspection, I'm not really sure why your original code didn't work.  If you run the assignment to @array4 twice, it does work.    
    
    `(@array4) =$line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g;`    
    `(@array4) =$line =~ m/.{8}units.ml/g;`    
    
I've made a separate question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961839/why-does-running-the-same-regex-twice-yield-different-results